# JaxB EclipseLink/MOXy : Supposedly empty date marshalled as today's date instead of no writing a node for it

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Once again I have a question about Eclipselink/MOXy with external metadata mapping file.

I have a reference xml which applies to a class. This xml contains data that applies to some but not always all the properties that the class can contain.

I also have a custom datetime adapter set for the date fields.

My problem is that the xml I'm unmarshalling does not contain any data for the endDate property, yet when I do this simple test :

- Unmarshall reference xml to the class
- Marshall that class to a new xml file
- Compare the two xml files

That property endDate (which should not be marshalled since it has not been set) is marshalled as 09/01/2012 17:05:28 (it's always marshalled as a new Date() set to the current time).

Here is a sample XML Metadata file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings  xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
                version="2.1">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="sample.clazz.Task" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
            <xml-root-element name="Task" />
            <xml-type prop-order="startDate endDate id ci ch cr" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="startDate" xml-path="StartDate/text()">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="utils.JaxBDateTimeAdapter" type="java.util.Date"/>
                </xml-element>
                <xml-element java-attribute="endDate" required="false" xml-path="EndDate/text()">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="utils.JaxBDateTimeAdapter" type="java.util.Date"/>
                </xml-element>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" xml-path="TaskId/text()" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="ci" xml-path="CIPR/text()" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="ch" xml-path="CHPR/text()" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="cr" xml-path="CRPR/text()" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Here is the class :

```
package sample.clazz;

public class Task{

    private int id;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String ci;
    private String ch;
    private String cr;

    public Task(){

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public String getCi() {
        return ci;
    }
    public void setCi(String ci) {
        this.ci = ci;
    }
    public String getCh() {
        return ch;
    }
    public void setCh(String ch) {
        this.ch = ch;
    }
    public String getCr() {
        return cr;
    }
    public void setCr(String cr) {
        this.cr = cr;
    }

}
```

Here is my custom DateTimeAdapter :

```
package utils;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class JaxBDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>  {


    @Override
    public String marshal(Date d) throws Exception {
        if(d != null){
            return DateUtil.getFormatedDateTimeString(d);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String d) throws Exception {
        if(d != null && !"".equals(d)){
            return DateUtil.getDateFromString(d);
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my reference XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Task>
    <TaskId>147</TaskId>
    <CRPR>0087</CRPR>
    <CIPR>A683557</CIPR>
    <CHPR>BV</CHPR>
    <StartDate>22/01/2009 20:56:29</StartDate>
</Task>
```

and Here is the XML I'm getting when re-marshalling the object :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Task>
    <TaskId>147</TaskId>
    <CRPR>0087</CRPR>
    <CIPR>A683557</CIPR>
    <CHPR>BV</CHPR>
    <StartDate>01/01/2012 20:56:29</StartDate>
    <EndDate>09/01/2012 17:05:28</EndDate> <!-- That element should not exist ! -->
</Task>
```

It seems like Jaxb generates a new date for the empty field, how can I tell him via the external metadata mapping file not to generate nodes for empty or null values ? I tried to set required=false on the metadata file, and I tried testing with my custom DateTimeAdapter if the values were null, but it seems Jaxb creates a new Date object and passes it to the marshal method of the Adapter. I cant think of any way of preventing him to do this.

As for my previous questions, I have no control over the incoming XML's or the model classes.

Please note : this data is a sample I wrote, it may not be accurate since I cannot expose real data or names, there might be some typing errors.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and I have not been able to reproduce your issue.  It may be possible that there is a problem in your `DateUtil` class.  The following is what I have tried:

**oxm.xml**

I made a small change to your metadatafile.  Basically I changed it to specify the package name on the `xml-bindings` element rather than the individual `java-type` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings  
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    version="2.3"
    package-name="sample.clazz">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Task" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
            <xml-root-element name="Task" />
            <xml-type prop-order="startDate endDate id ci ch cr" />
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="startDate" xml-path="StartDate/text()">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="forum8791782.JaxBDateTimeAdapter" type="java.util.Date"/>
                </xml-element>
                <xml-element java-attribute="endDate" required="false" xml-path="EndDate/text()">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="forum8791782.JaxBDateTimeAdapter" type="java.util.Date"/>
                </xml-element>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" xml-path="TaskId/text()" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="ci" xml-path="CIPR/text()" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="ch" xml-path="CHPR/text()" />
                <xml-element java-attribute="cr" xml-path="CRPR/text()" />
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**DateUtil**

You did not provide an implementation of `DateUtil` in your question, so I used the following.  My guess is there is code in your implementation of `DateUtil` that is causing the output that you are seeing:

```
package forum8791782;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {

    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    public static String getFormatedDateTimeString(Date d) {
        return formatter.format(d);
    }

    public static Date getDateFromString(String d) {
        try {
            return formatter.parse(d);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is the code I used to run this example.  `input.xml` is the reference XML you cite in your question:

```
package forum8791782;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.Version;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

import sample.clazz.Task;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Version.getVersionString());

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "forum8791782/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Task.class}, properties);

        File xml = new File("src/forum8791782/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Task task = (Task) u.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(task, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

The following is the output I get from running the sample code.  I do not see the `EndDate` element written out.

```
2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Task>
   <StartDate>22/01/2009 20:56:29</StartDate>
   <TaskId>147</TaskId>
   <CIPR>A683557</CIPR>
   <CHPR>BV</CHPR>
   <CRPR>0087</CRPR>
</Task>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, Blaise. I'll go and check deeper in the existing code to see if the problem comes from there. I'll also specify the package name in the xml-bindings tag, it feels indeed far more clean and practical. I did not provide the implementation of DateUtil because I made the assumption that if "d" (String or Date) is null or empty, the call to DateUtil's methods wouldn't even occur since the conditions of the "if" statement would not be filled. I will check that tomorrow morning and keep you informed.

Comment: You were right, it was model related. There's a moment where a new date is set, apparently the system date is needed later at runtime so that's working as intended. I mark this question as answered. Thanks.